Vercel does not render newly created blog, but this blog is being created in db and is visible on localhost
So i have deployed my nextjs + prisma + postgresql on Neon Service + cloudinary website on vercel.
I have added all env variables in the settings of this vercel project. Some of them are NEXT_PUBLIC ones, i don't know if it matters much but i'll mention it anyway.
But when i try to create a blog on this deployed website, it is being created in db and i can even see this blog on localhost, but this blog does not appear on deployed website.
What is the deal?
Basically, blogs can create only 1 specific person. i've added a btn like "i'm admin", and when you click on it it will ask for a password. I've hard coded this password in code, and i told this person this password so he and me are the only who know this password and can create blogs on website.
I didn't want to create these JWT/NextAuth/Clerk auth functionalities since creating blogs is planned to be accessible for only one specific person anyways.
There's users that watch content on website, and only one person who can create this content. I hope you understood logic behind ths website.
As i have already mentioned, when i create some blog from this deployed website, this blog is being added to db. So functionalities behind this vercel website works, i guess. This blog just can't be shown on website at any point.
There's no error in console when i create a post.
What is that kind of problem???
Maybe it's because of building? After solving this one of my questions (Error: Failed to collect page data from api/blogs/[blogId]) i've added:
"postinstall": "prisma generate && npm run build"

in scripts of package.json. In vercel settings of website build commands are default, npm run build. Idk maybe this is there reason...?
